Is the Sermon on the Mount about how to collapse the Roman government?
In college, I took a class from an evangelical hippie type of Christian. He spoke a lot about Jesus's teachings being about how to subvert the powers that be; since, they could not face the Romans directly. "Turn the other cheek" in a Middle East context was referring to forcing superiors to strike you, rather than slap you with their hand for washing. "Walk two miles when asked to walk one mile" was referring to a Roman law where the soldiers were only allowed to have a commoner carry their pack for one mile. Anything longer and they'd get fined.
So, with that context I look at the Sermon on the Mount a bit differently. "Render onto Ceasar what is Ceasar's" Means use the Denarius only for paying taxes, and other parts of the sermon suggest an alternative currency should be adopted by the Christians for exchanging goods and services between themselves. If that's what he meant and Christianity grew that practice would make Rome fall by collapsing their currency.
The Israelites chose Barabas over Jesus, since they did not understand his teachings, and Barabas offered a more direct means of confronting the Roman government; though, less likely to be successful. Christs teachings would have taken hundreds of years to end the Romans at the time, through subversion.
Has there been any scholarship on this means of thinking about the Sermon on the Mount? Think there is something here?

Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below). Without a textual reference to scripture itself, your question may be considered off-topic by the Community or by the Moderators. Personally, my view is that the whole balance of the book of Matthew indicates a far deeper concept than the superficial one you suggest. The kingdom of the heavens is the concept and many texts in both Matthew and the other gospels show that the purpose of Jesus of Nazareth was defintiely not what you propose.

I don't believe in his divinity. I'm looking at it from a practical perspective, over his teachings. I do interpret the bible through Nietzsche's Thus Spoke Zarathustra, and it makes sense based on his critique of Christianity. Zarathustra, whether being an allegory for Christ, Socrates, or Osiris serves the same purpose.
Those quotes I cited paraphrase lines in the sermon. I don't remember which denomination the guy was from.
According to what I've found the Jews were unhappy with him not leading a direct rebellion, what they did not realize his rebellion was through subversion.

This more or less says what I'm getting at. The meaning of the bible changes if you have studied the history of the time period it refers to.
https://enterthebible.org/was-jesus-a-threat-to-the-roman-empire-mary-hinkle-shore

The sermon on the mount found in Matt 5, 6, & 7 is essentially Jesus commentary and expansion on the moral teachings in the Torah.

@ZeroPhase says "The meaning of the bible changes if … ." — The meaning of the Bible doesn't change; it is your understanding of it that changes. — This site is about the intended meaning of scripture, and so this question isn't appropriate here.  Christianity Stack Exchange is a more appropriate place for asking about interpretation. But if you do ask there, don't ask "Is it about …" (asking for truth) or "Think there is …" (soliciting opinion). Your "Has there been any scholarship …" question though is appropriate.

I am asking about the intended meaning of scripture. The cultural context of the language in the bible matters. From my understanding of hermeneutics post-Heidegger the observer is always part of the interpretation of the text.
Do I need to quote the specific parts on the sermon on the mount that points to Christianity being a revolutionary movement against Rome, and that's why Christ was crucified since it threatened their rule? There are multiple levels of interpretation. I'm just interested in the social aspect of the Sermon. Christ was speaking in metaphors.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Although the question may be closed from lack of biblical specificity - or migrated to C.se - let me say that there has indeed been much scholarship about how the Sermon on the Mount relates to Israel's oppression by Rome.

The question addresses Jesus' teaching about turning the other cheek.

This article deals with the Sermon in the context of Roman oppression generally.

Progressive theologian Walter Wink understood the Sermon as a call to non-violent resistance.


You may also want to look at the sermons of Martin Luther King Jr., who referred often to Jesus' teachings in the Sermon. Liberation theologians such as  Gustavo Gutiérrez and Leonardo Boff, wrote volumes about the socio-economic situation of Jesus' hearers under Roman oppression.
